# Django Rest Api with Pandas

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework to make an api of my data. I am making an app that takes into account user data and remove outliers from that data using Pandas. I am able to present my data on frontend using django templates but somehow I am not able to make an API containing the statistical data using django-rest-framework . Can someone explain it and please help me to rectify my errors and also provide the necessary code

Here is my code

```
class Data(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    Age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Weight = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Height = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Sugar = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name
```

My Serializer Class

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

my views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    con = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from visualapp_health", con)
    a = df.fillna(0)
    a['x-Mean'] = abs(a['Age'] - a['Age'].mean())
    a['1.96*std'] = 1.96*a['Age'].std()
    a['Outlier'] = abs(a['Age'] - a['Age'].mean()) > 1.96*a['Age'].std()
    con.close()
    return render(request, 'visual.html', {'visual': a})
```

I am able to get all the Data when using Django templates but somehow I don't able to understand how to make an API of all the data using django-rest- framework.

[image: using django templates]

[image: Using api all data is not visible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it I used django-pandas library and it worked and there is no need to connect to the database just convert your django queryset to pandas dataframe.